# How do I basically embed an audio player into my website using html?

Tags: html, audio

I know this question has been asked before but I'm still having a little trouble. I want to embed small mp3 files onto a website page at various points. I've recorded these files and have them downloaded in (you guessed it) my downloads. If I were to use something like this:

```html
 <audio src="something.mp3" controls></audio>
```

How would I create a pathway for that to link to my audio file so that everyone else can listen to it. I know it's probably super simple but I'm still having a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to put your mp3 on the server together with the html file, and use relative paths.

if you have your html file and mp3 files in the same directory

```
public_html/
  index.html
  something.mp3
```

then  you can just keep the code as it is now.

If you want to keep mp3s in a subdirectory

```
public_html/
  index.html
  mp3/
    something.mp3
```

Then you will need to specify the path in relation to the position of the html file within the directory tree.

```
<audio src="mp3/something.mp3">
```

To be clear: you can not use the mp3 file you have in your Downloads on the website, you need to put the mp3 on the server first. (You can actually put them on some free service, like Dropbox, and link to them from your website).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**EMBEDDING BACKGROUND SOUND USING META:**

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;URL='ourmusic.wav'" >
```

**EMBEDDING AUDIO:**

```
<bgsound src="he-knows.wav" LOOP="-1" > 
<EMBED SRC="he-knows.mp3" HIDDEN="true" AUTOSTART="true" LOOP="infinite" Height=145 width=160></EMBED>
```

**Using the Object Tag:**

```
<object data="music.wav" type="audio/x-mplayer2" width="320" height="240">
<param name="src" value="music.wav">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">
<param name="autoStart" value="0">
Hear the sound : <a href="music.wav">music</a>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plenty of things.

```
<audio controls>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"
         type='audio/mp4'>
 <!-- The next two lines are only executed if the browser doesn't support MP4 files -->
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
         type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
 <!-- The next line will only be executed if the browser doesn't support the <audio> tag-->
 <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

Or

```
<embed serc="YourMusic.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" width="2" height="0">
  </embed>
```

Comment: thanks Selva but how would I link my specific mp3 that is located in my downloads into the audio tag? what pathway would i have to recite? in other words, for your second example, what would I put in "YourMusic.mp3"

Comment: You have to give folder path of your file for example :  <embed serc="download/YourMusic.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" width="2" height="0">
  </embed>